# Check if display is none using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript and want to hit a button however if the button is "display:none" then I would like to skip it.

So currently I have this code:

```
var sf = document.querySelectorAll(input.button")[0];
```

Now as an example there may be other "input.buttons" on the page that are set to "display:none", I would like to skip these and only click on the visible one.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you click on a button if it's not displayed? This question makes no sense!

Comment: Well the button may be there but the css styling can be set to display:none which still lets the button exist but not viewable. Since i'm using this for web scraping the script will still hit the first button it comes across

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `var sf = document.querySelectorAll(input.button")[0];`

There is problem in above statement. `document.querySelectorAll(input.button")[0]` will return an empty array if you want to select an input of type button use the following

```
var sf = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']");        // array of button
var sf = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']").[0];    // first index element
```

assume you `sf is an array`

```
for (var i = 0; i < sf.length; i++) {
    if (sf[i].style.display != "none") {
        console.log(elem[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To check for `display: none` in jquery is using sub-selectors (usually called) `:visible`.

```
if(document.getElementById("id").is(':visible')){
 // YES, ITS WORKING..!
}
```

Comment: What happened? @pretty danger

Comment: Thanks but I needed something in javascript, I plan to re-do it in jquery sometime in the future.